# How to filter mysql rows in PHP where data is either empty or 0

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to find is there is an efficient way to do a query which can ignore rows of data where any column has a value of 0 or empty

My current query looks like this:

```
$query = "SELECT AVG(concept1) AS c1, AVG(concept2) AS c2, AVG(concept3) AS c3, AVG(concept4) AS c4, AVG(concept5) AS c5, AVG(concept6) AS c6 FROM KeyPad";
```

Now I dont want to count rows while averaging where any column data is 0 or null.

eg.

```
-----------------------------------------
|concept1  | concept2  | concept3  | ...
-----------------------------------------
| 1.2      |   3.2     |    0      | ...
| 2.4      |   4.1     |    2.1    | ...
| 3.2      |   5.1     |    2.2    | ...
| 4.3      |   3.2     |    5.3    | ...
| 1.2      |   0       |    3.2    | ...
------------------------------------------
```

When I run my query, I only want to generate average using data from rows 2,3,4 and ignore all data from rows 1 and 5.

I read that I can use something like COALESCE but not sure if it can work for averaging values.

Any suggestions which direction should I explore?

## Additional Notes (updated):

I may not have explained correctly.
When I say ignore rows, I mean if one item inn the row is 0, I want to ignore all the other items in the rows while averaging those columns too.

So in the example table above, the average for Column1 will be:
(2.4+3.2+4.3) / 3 because First row in column 3 is 0 and last row in column 2 is also 0. So other columns will also need to ignore these two rows while calculating the average.

I hope that clarifies my problem.

Comment: can you show us sample output in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this, **it will not consider row with value `0` and `AVG` itself excludes `null` values**

```
SELECT AVG(NULLIF(concept4, 0)) FROM KeyPad;
```

or using case ([sample demo link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c5b12/5/0))

```
SELECT AVG(case  
              when concept1 = 0 then null
              else concept1
           end) as c1
FROM KeyPad
```

so your full query:

```
SELECT AVG(NULLIF(concept1,0)) AS c1,
       AVG(NULLIF(concept2,0)) AS c2,
       AVG(NULLIF(concept3,0)) AS c3,
       AVG(NULLIF(concept4,0)) AS c4,
       AVG(NULLIF(concept5,0)) AS c5,
       AVG(NULLIF(concept6,0)) AS c6
FROM KeyPad
```

If you want you can add condition in `WHERE` similar like this according to your requirement:

```
SELECT AVG(concept1) AS c1
FROM KeyPad
WHERE concept1 > 0
```

> Note: Where condition may change your desired output if grouped
>   wrongly with more than one column. If you want to check for individual field then use `NULLIF`
>   or `CASE`

Comment: Thanks Jigar, does it mean it will only check 0 in column 4? What if I want to check 0 in every column?

Comment: oh, maybe i missunderstood, i should use this syntax for each AVG, right?

Comment: yes, exactly . You have use this syntax for all column

Comment: Thanks, let me try.... also any suggestion, if I want to do a Select * from... statement, then how do I ignore the 0 rows?

Comment: It can be accomplished with where condition on field

Comment: I tried your code on my server, but it didnt work.... It is still not ignoring the rows with 0 value in one of the column

Comment: check the `case` logic as second option to  `iNULLIF `

Comment: I am trying all your solutions, but its not working.

Comment: This is my edited query now:
$q = "SELECT AVG(case when concept1 = 0 then null else concept1 end) AS c1, AVG(case when concept2 = 0 then null else concept2 end) AS c2, AVG(case when concept3 = 0 then null else concept3 end) AS c3, AVG(case when concept4 = 0 then null else concept4 end) AS c4, AVG(case when concept5 = 0 then null else concept5 end) AS c5, AVG(case when concept6 = 0 then null else concept6 end) AS c6 FROM KeyPad WHERE race = '".$r."'";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155059/discussion-between-jigar-shah-and-ssdesign).

Comment: I had to write a very long statement for this to work. 
-----
$q = "SELECT AVG(case when concept1=0 or concept2=0 or concept3=0 or concept4=0 or concept5=0 or concept6=0 then null else concept1 end) AS c1, AVG(case when concept1=0 or concept2=0 or concept3=0 or concept4=0 or concept5=0 or concept6=0 then null else concept2 end) AS c2, AVG(case when concept1=0 or concept2=0 or concept3=0 or concept4=0 or concept5=0 or concept6=0 then null else concept3 end) AS c3,...and so on AND race = '".$r."'";

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting you right, Below query will help you:

```
$query = "SELECT AVG(concept1) AS c1, AVG(concept2) AS c2, AVG(concept3) AS c3 FROM KeyPad where (concept1 IS NOT NULL OR concept1 != 0) AND (concept2 IS NOT NULL OR concept2 != 0) AND (concept3 IS NOT NULL OR concept3 != 0");
```

Here Just add till concept3 you can do with more columns.

Comment: no, OP may not get the desired output as where condition is used. Row  with zero value in any column will be skipped. OP want to skip zero for particular field, not from any column

Comment: The desired output is that the result ignores all the rows where any column has value 0

Comment: what is the issue with above query?

Comment: when I run your solution, the rows are not getting ignored.

Comment: @ssdesign try with '0'

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this also

```
$query = "SELECT 
            sum(concept1) AS c1, sum(if(concept1 is not null or concept1 != '',1,0 )) as c1_count,
            sum(concept2) AS c2, sum(if(concept2 is not null or concept2 != '',1,0 )) as c2_count
        FROM 
            KeyPad";
```

And on front end you can do the Division

OR

```
$query = "SELECT 
            ( sum(concept1) / sum(if(concept1 is not null or concept1 != '',1,0 )) ) as c1,
            ( sum(concept2) / sum(if(concept2 is not null or concept2 != '',1,0 )) ) as c2
        FROM 
            KeyPad";
```